# postgresql query_to_xml remove tag 'row'

Tags: xml, postgresql

I am newbie on postgreql , and working on the xml 
As from the document i have used following query :

```
select xmlelement(name user,query_to_xml('select cu_fname,cu_sname,cu_id from p_customers',true,true,''))
```

And the result is

```
<user>
<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <cu_fname>Test</cu_fname>
  <cu_sname>user</cu_sname>
  <cu_id>66976662</cu_id>
</row>

<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <cu_fname>Test</cu_fname>
  <cu_sname>User</cu_sname>
  <cu_id>60134543</cu_id>
</row>

<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <cu_fname>Test</cu_fname>
  <cu_sname>User</cu_sname>
  <cu_id>14483654</cu_id>
</row>

</user>
```

But my expectation is :

```
<user >
  <cu_fname>Test</cu_fname>
  <cu_sname>user</cu_sname>
  <cu_id>66976662</cu_id>
</user>

<user>
  <cu_fname>Test</cu_fname>
  <cu_sname>User</cu_sname>
  <cu_id>60134543</cu_id>
</user>

<user >
  <cu_fname>Test</cu_fname>
  <cu_sname>User</cu_sname>
  <cu_id>14483654</cu_id>
</user>
```

Can you help me out .

Thank You in Advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want:

```
select xmlelement(name user,xmlforest(cu_fname,cu_sname,cu_id)) 
from p_customers;
```

?..

Comment: Above query only gives one node . 

<user><cu_fname>Rohan</cu_fname><cu_sname>Ale</cu_sname><cu_id>702268</cu_id></user>

where the table has many rows .. i only get one row

Answer (score 2):

You can first get the user elements and then aggregate them as:

```
select XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(name user, xmlforest(cu_fname,cu_sname,cu_id))) from p_customers;
```